# XMLHTTP request doesn't get to the xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 state

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

For my Ajax call, I created an xmlhttp object. When I "open" it I guess it does open but it never gets to the `xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200` state. I have tried to run the hidden page using `window.open` and it shows no error.

Previously I did use AJAX on another page and it worked just fine. I do think that `xmlhttp` request do open because `document.getElementById('Approval' + id).innerHTML = 'Loading...';` does work, but it just doesn't get to the `xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200` state at all.

Instead, very very shortly after it shows "Loading..." where I designed it to show (which is abnormal because the hidden page sends emails which usually takes a lot of time), it shows the previous text. I have not encountered this before.

Below is my code

```
var xmlhttp;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }


            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    document.getElementById('Approval' + id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }

                else {

                    document.getElementById('Approval' + id).innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "AJAX%20pages/UploadDecisionAbsenceRequest.aspx?decision=" + decision + '&position=' + position + '&id=' + id, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            //window.open("AJAX%20pages/UploadDecisionAbsenceRequest.aspx?decision=" + decision + '&position=' + position + '&id=' + id,'','width=200, height = 100');
```

Also after I try to know the state of the xmlhttp request, by writing this line of code:

```
document.getElementById('Approval' + id).innerHTML = "Now (readystate) " + xmlhttp.readystate + " and status " + xmlhttp.status;
```

all I got was Now (readystate) undefined and status 0 and from there it didn't go any further.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

can not be used before opening the request. Also after that check weather data.length is correct or not.

Use

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "AJAX%20pages/UploadDecisionAbsenceRequest.aspx?decision=" + decision + '&position=' + position + '&id=' + id, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

            xmlhttp.send();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tU8JH/1/)**

Comment: Ok please forget about xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
because without that it still doesn't work...

Comment: @ThaoTruong , can you check in the firebug /chrome Inspector, what is the url it is trying to access. Most probably issue will be with the url. I can see a % in your url. Hope it is correct.

Comment: I did get the url it tries to open and open it in a new window and it worked :(